# Async file write performance

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous

Why writing many files asynchronously is slower than synchronously? Synchronous version takes 30 seconds to complete, async takes 40 seconds. I thought it will be faster because it can write files concurrently.

```
void Write()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        File.WriteAllText($"test{i}", "TEST");
    }
}

async Task WriteAsync()
{
    Task[] fileTasks = new Task[100000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        fileTasks[i] = File.WriteAllTextAsync($"test{i}", "TEST");
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(fileTasks);
}
```

Comment: [seems like an open bug](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23196)

Comment: Hard drives have to move heads around so async can be much slower. Also the operating system does all sorts of locks so you don't corrupt file allocation tables. There's no reason to think that parallelizing IO will make it quicker. It's usually slower.

Comment: @styx - What bug?

Comment: If your program is bottlenecked on I/O speed, trying to perform more I/O in parallel won't achieve any speedup

Comment: @Enigmativity I tried this on SSD, not hard drive

Comment: @MeGaLoDoN - It still has the same limitation. They don't do parallel writes. They just have significantly reduced seek times.

Comment: Additional to the IO congestion you also need to see that in your test you write tiny files and create a ton of tasks which will have a significant overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought it will be faster because it can write file s concurrently.

Yes, and no. All disks tend to perform best when writing large amounts of sequential data. This effect is most pronounced for HDDs, where the write head has to physically move. But it also affects SSD to a lesser extent.

SSDs *can* write data concurrently, So having a large queue of commands *may* be a benefit since it allows the drive to do things in parallel. But this does not mean you need to write many files concurrently, writing a large amount of data to a single file should be enough to keep a decent queue of commands for the drive.

Your test is also kind of extreme, with a very large number of really tiny files. While this will absolutely stress the drive with random writes, it may also stress the task scheduling in ways that can cause overheads. It may also cause contention issues in the file system that has to synchronize all requests.

In the end I would not *expect* IO operations to perform better when run concurrently. I may *try* to use some amount of concurrency to check if it is a benefit for my specific workload and my specific hardware. I can't tell what the specific limitation is in your case, but your results are within my expectations.